# How to override isHidden/setHidden/hidden in UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, polymorphism, overriding

I would like to override the hide functionality in my UIView derived class to animate hide/show using alpha (i.e. encapsulate the functionality). As this seems to be just basic OO I tried the obvious trick of just providing a new function in my class as follows:

```
-(BOOL)isHidden {
    return [super isHidden];
}

- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden {
    CGFloat newAlpha = 0.75f;
    if (self.hidden == NO) {
        newAlpha = 0.0;
    }
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations: ^() {
        self.alpha = newAlpha;}];
}
```

... doesn't work. I've tried many combinations but can't seem to override, the UIView methods just keep getting called - have I gone mad? is there a restriction that I am failing to understand?

Comment: Have you tried by adding this methods in a UIView category? I am not sure if it will work or not, but you can give it a try.

Comment: A category on UIView would override the behavior for all UIView's. Probably not what the OP wants. If this code is in a UIView subclass then it should work...

Comment: I notice that you aren't calling `[super setHidden:]`.

Comment: Where have you added these methods? Is the class they are in actually instantiated?

Comment: As comments suggest - I don't want to override it everywhere. @Wain I have derived a class from UIView and the methods are in there but they don't get called/are-ignored.

Comment: And you have checked that your custom view subclass is instantiated where you expect it to be?

Comment: @Wain yes - my custom class is instantiated by the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your sense but I hope you are missing the completion block. So simply try:

```
- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)hidden {

    CGFloat newAlpha = 0.75f;

    if (self.hidden == NO) {
        newAlpha = 0.0;
    }

    UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

         self.alpha = newAlpha;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [super setHidden:hidden];
    }
}
```

In the completion block you have to set the hidden property of the UIView.

Comment: I guess, this will call setHidden: method recursively.

Comment: Thanks, Yes it has to be [super setHidden:hidden];

Comment: Hi Goppinath, the functionality isn't the problem - it's the polymorphic behaviour that I am struggling with i.e. overridding the method has no effect/is-ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - answering my own question after a few months of learning ...

I'm a doofus and must have been having a bad day - the overriding code in my question works perfectly unless you do the idiotic thing I did which was to add an override property in my header file:

```
@property(nonatomic,getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;
```

Adding this to the header means that my isHidden/setHidden are not treated as overloaded methods at all i.e. I broke the polymorphism.